# Are the effects of faraday's law of induction worth considering in this experiment?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electricity, collision

In my intro to physics lab at uni, we did an experiment where we were supposed to measure the amount of kinetic energy and momentum before and after collisions between two carts. For some reason, there was a HUGE amount of momentum and kinetic energy lost during the elastic collisions, something like 83% momentum and 50% of kinetic energy. I've already finished typing my report and I don't plan on editing it, but I'm curious. We forced an elastic collision by using carts with magnetic bumpers. Instead of hitting each other, the magnets in each cart pushed the other cart in the opposite direction. Since the carts were made of metal, I was wondering if the fluctuating magnetic field would induce a current in the carts and, if so, would this account for at least some of the lost energy and momentum? (Even if it does, I imagine that the difference is probably not measurable my equipment, which only measured velocity in m/s to 2 decimal places.)

I think that the carts were a plastic frame covered by metal plates. Altogether they each were about 500g. We also varied the mass of the carts by placing metal bars on the carts, also weighing 500g each.

Comment: There can be a loss of energy, but no loss of momentum, unless your magnets interact with the ground in some ways. The loss of momentum and part of the loss of energy is because of friction.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking that some momentum would be "lost" because the induced current means moving electrons, but I guess that that momentum would be completely beyond the precision of my instruments since electrons have very little mass and move very slowly.

Comment: Think about the same experiment in space, so that there is nothing else that momentum could be transferred to. Then one can apply momentum conservation and there is really no way that it can change. As long as the carts have contact with the ground or the table that is where the momentum goes, but the magnets have nothing to do with that, right?

Comment: The same argument does not work for energy because energy can always be converted to heat, which is exactly what the eddy currents would be doing.

Comment: So, you're saying no momentum is lost to electrons at all?

Comment: Momentum is transferred, but the momentum of the entire system of all carts (and I think that is what you are referring to?) stays the same without the friction forces to the ground.

Comment: By momentum, I mean the quantity calculated by measuring the velocity of the carts and multiplying by their masses which I also measured :)